# Conjecture on zeros of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I have a conjecture that I can´t prove nor disprove, any help on doing so  will be very grateful.

> Let $f: \{z: |z|<2\} \to \mathbb C$ be a non constant analytic function such that if $|z|=1$ then $|f(z)|=1$.
>
> Is it true that the zeros of $f$ can not be in $\{ z: 1/2< |z| < 2 \}$ ?

I have successfully proven, by the maximum modulus theorem, that $f$ must have a zero inside $\{ z: |z|<1 \}$. However, I can not seem to prove that all the zeros must be in $\{ z:|z| < 1/2 \}$, neither to find a counter example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is true. If a function is unimodular on the unit circle ($|f(z)|=1$), you can use [Schwarz reflection principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449671/the-schwarz-reflection-principle-for-a-circle) that tells you that the zeros and poles are symmetric wrt the unit circle ($z\ \leftrightarrow\ \bar{z}^{-1}$). There are no poles inside $|z|=1$, so there are no zeros outside $|z|=1$ for the analytical continuation. All poles are outside $|z|=2$ then all zeros are inside $|z|=1/2$.

Comment: Neat. I surprisingly never encountered this result before. $+1$

Comment: @A.G. Thank you for your prompt answer. Then If I get you right, my conjecture follows by using that since $f$ is unimodular then it is a rational function, also by the maximum principle we get that all zeros of $f$ must be in $\{z:|z|<1\}$, say $Z(f)=\{z_1, \cdots, z_n\}\subset \{z:|z|<1\}$ are all the zeros of $f$, then $P(f)=\left\{\left(\overline{z_1}\right)^{-1}, \cdots, \left(\overline{z_n}\right)^{-1}\right\} \subset \{z:|z|>1\}$ are the poles of $f$, however, since in this case $P(f) \subset \{|z|\geq 2\}$ we conclude that $Z(f)\subset \{z : |z|<1/2\}$??

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín That's right. Under the conditions the function is a [finite Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Finite_Blaschke_products).