# Schwarz Reflection Principle on a unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a analytic function defined on $\bar{D}(0;1)$ and has real value on the boundary. I'm trying to show $f$ can be extended to entire plane by $$g(z) = \begin{cases}f(z) &, \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1\\ \frac{1}{\overline{f(\overline{z}^{-1})}},  &, \lvert z\rvert > 1\end{cases}
$$
I tried to use $\gamma(z)=e^{iz}$, which sends real axis to unit circle, for Schwarz Reflection Principle. But I did not get the result. May I get a help?

Comment: You may find guidance in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449671/the-schwarz-reflection-principle-for-a-circle), especially by looking on @DanielFischer answer.

Comment: I checked that question, but I couldn't know how to get $\frac{1}{\overline{f(\overline{z}^{-1})}}$

Answer (score 3):

You can write various forms of the reflection principle, it seems to me that the formula that you are writing is correct for a map from unit disk to C which maps a unit circle to a unit circle (and not the real axis).
In the case of a map from unit disk which maps the boundary to the real axis the formula is
$$ g(z) = \begin{cases} f(z) \quad |z|\leq 1, \\ \overline{f(\frac{1}{\bar{z}})} \quad |z|>1 \end{cases} $$
which is what TrialAndError has.

Comment: Note this differs from the linked question, as we have the boundary real in this case, but they had the boundary tending to |f| = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $f$ is real on the boundary, then, for $|z|=1$,
\begin{align}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_{n}z^{n} & = \overline{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_{n}z^{n}} \\
    & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\overline{f_{n}z^{n}} \\
    & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\overline{f_n}\frac{1}{z^{n}}.
\end{align}

Comment: And therefore $f$ is the real constant $f_0.$